# Serial voting reversed

Tags: support, voting, reputation

I've had this message before in the *recent achievments reputation*... box. I'm guessing that it's because someone has more than one account with philosophy stackexchange?

Comment: Is your question "What does this mean?"?

Comment: @Keelan yes! sorry ha

Comment: No problem. I thought so, but wasn't entirely sure.

Answer (score 5):

Serial voting means that one person has up- or downvoted a large number of your posts in a short period of time.

Serial upvoting occurs when a user appreciates your work and wants to give you a lot of reputation in return. It also occurs when two users have agreed to upvote the posts of the other, or when a user creates a 'sock puppet' account, just to upvote the posts of his main account.

Serial downvoting occurs when a user has a grudge against you.

These kind of reputation changes are reverted because votes are meant to reflect the content of a post, not the appreciation of the author.

You don't need to worry about this message: in all but a few cases this is someone else's fault - and when it is your fault, you know it.

[More information on the network-wide Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/205264).